# How to get an access to the parameters in non-controller class in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a class that doesn't have access to the service container (because it does not extends the Controler class).

How can I get access to the parameters from **parameters.ini** in that class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of:

1. Define your class as a service and inject the parameters into it. This is the cleanest solution.

   Ex:

   ```
   // parameters.ini
   my_param: fooBar

   // services.yml
   tests.example:
     class: some\class
     arguments: [%my_param%]
   ```

   `fooBar` will now be passed to your class constructor.
2. Define your class as a service and inject the `container` service into it. This is **not** recommended and I'm only listing it because it's technically possible.

Comment: After defining your class as service you must call the service exclusively from the service container (`$this->get('tests.example');` in the controller) and must not create it manually. Take a look at the official documentation at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html